# How to create an internal rewrite from folder to subdomain using php and .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dynamic, subdomain

i am trying to setup my multilanguage site with some kind of special setup. I have two domains and
with one of these domains various languages the other domain is only for one language

```
www.example.de #for german
www.example.com #for us english
www.example.com/es #for spanish
www.example.com/uk #for uk english
```

the site is managed by polylang plugin with the setting language per directory

```
www.example.com/de #for german
www.example.com/us #for us english
www.example.com/es #for spanish
www.example.com/uk #for uk english
```

I try to do an internal rewrite in .htaccess
if people access  `example.de` I want to access data stored in `example.com/de`

I tried some solutions i found here, but none matches my exakt problem.
Can someone help me with a solution?

thanks

Comment: Kindly do add your tried htaccess Rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Presumably `example.com` and `example.de` point to the same place? So, `example.com/de` and `example.de/de` point to the same place, so there's no need to "rewrite" across domains? (You can't "rewrite" across domains; you would need to implement a _reverse proxy_.) However, I suspect you'll need to manage all this in WordPress itself, not `.htaccess`, since WordPress won't (by default) see the rewritten URL, only the URL that has been requested.

Comment: "How to create an internal rewrite from folder to subdomain ..." - From the example in your question you don't have any "subdomains" and the "rewrite" is in the opposite direction... from TLD to folder. (?!)

Comment: Yeah I am sorry, I got a bit confused while writing my question. I need to rewrite from TLD to folder.

I thought about a solution like any requests from `http://www.example.de/`  will lead internally to `http://www.example.com/de`  - so that polylang plugin can handle it.